# Understand and implement power spectral density

Tags: matlab

I have problems when it comes to understand the power spectral density (especially the difference between discrete and continuous). This is probably a "beginner" question but I hope that someone has the time to clarify this for me since literature gave me contradictory results and confused me even more.

I found two terms which are seemingly not the same:

1. Power density spectrum
2. Power spectral density (some books say its the scaled power density spectrum)

So in my understanding the power spectral density (Sxx) should give the power per Hz. For a continuous signal it can be calculated with the fourier transform of the autocorrelation function (through the integral the unit would be W/Hz so this seems fine). Followingly the signals power can be calculated by the total integral of Sxx.

But how to calculate it for a discrete and finite signal? ("by hand" and not just use pwelch)

If I apply the autocorrelation and use the fft in this case I obtain: `Sxx_disc=1/N*abs(fft(x)).^2`  with `N=length(x)`

But if I use `sum(Sxx_disc)` it doesn't give me the right signalpower which should be: `Px_disc=1/N*sum(abs(x).^2)`.
This Px_disc I just obtain with `sum(Sxx_disc)/N` - but why do I have to divide by N again?

Thank you for any kind of help! Klaus

Comment: They're both the magnitude squared of the frequency samples. Some texts might scale them differently than others, but it's not important. The easiest way to calculate it is to take the DFT of the signal and then square it's magnitude.  For instance, `Sxx = abs(fft(x)).^2` or `X = fft(x); Sxx = X .* conj(X)`. I don't know why you are summing the result of the autocorrelation in the time domain. You can also take the DFT of the autoforrelation to get `Sxx`, but that's different than just summing.